# Passsing URL with delegate when didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have made a camera object that conforms to `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`. Once the video is recorded, I am going to transfer the URL through a delegate using `func capture()`. The problem is that for some reason  when this function is called, the video seems to actually not be done recording, because `urlDelegate?.URL` always debugs to `nil`, though `outputURL` has a value. There's clearly a synch problem, but I am not understanding why.
 How should I fix this, and more importantly why is the video not done when using `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt`

```
func capture(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
        if error == nil {
            urlDelegate?.URL = outputURL
        }

    }
```

Even tried this, still nil:

```
func capture(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated.qosClass).async {
                let url = self.outputURL
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let completedURL = url {
                        self.urlDelegate?.URL = completedURL
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you check the error object in the delegate? Is it nil?

Comment: @DocForNoc no, it's just the delegate. the function actually works, it gives no error, but I can see the delegate is nil when debugging

Comment: you are accessing the wrong object. it should be `outputFileURL` and it is not optional so there is no need to unwrap it.Btw your method signature it is wrong. it should be `func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, 
didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, 
           from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], 
          error: Error?)`

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is that the [fileoutput method signature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutputrecordingdelegate/1390612-fileoutput) is wrong. You can also check the other [AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutputrecordingdelegate) methods.

The correct method signature is:

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?)
```

Besides that you are accessing the wrong object. It should be `outputFileURL` instead of `outputURL` and it is not optional so there is no need to unwrap.

Comment: I see what you are saying, the interesting thing is that func fileOutput is not recognized. Moreover, when adopting AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate, the compiler is asking me to implement the func capture() as I have it. Could this be because my Camera class is a subclass of NSObject?

Comment: I think the 2 functions are the same, just different versions of swift. So it looks like to fix what I really need is a completion handler